# 403 Forbidden error after installing patches magento

Tags: magento, patch

I have installed following security patchs in my site of magento:
4291,6237,7616,5344,5994,6285,6482,6788,7405. But now whenever I try to run any ajax request in admin of magento (logging in as a user). I tried setting permissions of app folder to even 777 but then also it is not working.
My site is blocked, please help.
I think this is because of 6788 patch but I am not sure.
There is new section of "Block" and "Variable" in permissions. Do I need to add any blocks or variables in this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a custom module for this? Can you post your xml config of the admin routers?

Comment: It worked after adding _isAllowed() in controller of custom module, as mentioned here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285

Comment: This is why I was asking if you were using a custom module. I already had an answer in concept. I will post this anyway for others with the same problem.

Comment: Welcome. Maybe you can mark this as correct anwer for others with same question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be caused by patch SUPEE-6285.
This patch changes the default return value of `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_isAllowed()` from `true` to `Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('admin')`.
This can restrict permission to modules for restricted admin accounts.

You can solve this by adding following function to the admin controller of your module:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: now it has started throwing 404 error (after some time). Do you know the reason for this?